# Is cloning a custom struct that can't implement Copy every time you want to use it the best way to do it?

Tags: rust

I have a struct that has a `Vec` field and cannot implement `Copy`:

```
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct MyStruct {
    field: Vec<i32>,
}

impl MyStruct {
    fn new () -> MyStruct {
        MyStruct {
            field: vec![1, 2],
        }
    }

    fn overwrite(&mut self, strt: MyStruct) {
        self.field = strt.field;
    }
}
```

If I want to use it multiple times later in my code, I have to `clone()` it every time:

```
fn main() {
    let mut s = MyStruct::new();
    let s2 = MyStruct::new();

    s.overwrite(s2.clone());

    println!("{:?}", s2);
}
```

This works fine, but is this the best way to accomplish this task? Are there any other, more idiomatic ways?

Comment: This is rather too vague to say what's idiomatic. Why do you need to overwrite the data this way, and why do you need to keep the data source (`s2` in your example) around?

Comment: I agree with Sebastian Redl — if you *have* to transfer ownership but also still maintain ownership, then your only solution is to clone (or copy when possible) the item. Maybe you don't need to transfer ownership and could use a reference. Maybe you could use shared ownership like an `Rc` or `Arc`.

Comment: The `let mut s` doesn't seem to add anything to the example... maybe something got lost in copy-paste?

Comment: @Shepmaster my question is purely theoretical, this example is here just to illustrate what I mean. I was checking my code and noticed that I have a lot of structs which cant implement copy and sometimes I have to call a lot of methods that consume the struct on the same struct. Having like 20 lines of code cloning the same struct just seemed a bit ugly. Maybe you are right and my question _is_ too vague.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's review our data handling story:

- **moving** is about transferring ownership, because the original variable is no longer necessary
- **cloning** is about creating a duplicate, so as to be able to use both the original and the new value independently
- **borrowing** is about temporarily lending a reference for a controlled amount of time, so as to be able to use the original variable before and after (and possibly, if borrowed with `&` and not `&mut`, in a limited manner during)

In your case, you should be using *borrowing* here.

```
fn overwrite(&mut self, strt: &MyStruct) {
//                            ^
    self.field = strt.field.clone();
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = MyStruct::new();
    let s2 = MyStruct::new();

    s.overwrite(&s2);
    //          ^

    println!("{:?}", s2);
}
```

For an in-depth treatment of the concept, read [the Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ownership.html). And if you come from a garbage collected language background, the chapters 4.7 to 4.10 are REALLY a must read.

Comment: Thanks. I've read the book, still getting confused sometimes. Btw the code as you wrote it still gives the borrowed content error @ `self.field = strt.field`

Comment: @ehsisthatsweird: oopsie, the `field` itself has to be cloned of course :)